# Getting 2 rows effected instead of 1 while calling MySQL stored procedure in MySql Workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am new to stored procedures. First I defined stored procedure like this in MySQL. I am suing MySQL Workbench 6.2

```
delimiter //
create procedure usp_processUser(
    in vu360UserId bigint(20), 
    in vu360UserNamevarchar(255), 
    in vu360UserGuid varchar(50),
    in email varchar(50),
    in firstName varchar(255),
    in lastName varchar(255),
    in notifyLicenseExpiration bit(1),
    in createdDate timestamp,
    in updatedDate timestamp
)
begin
    if not exists(select * from `AutoAlerts`.`User` where VU360UserID = vu360UserId)
    then
        insert into `AutoAlerts`.`User` (`VU360UserID`, `VU360UserName`, `UserGuid`, `Email`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Notify_License_Expiration`, CreatedDate) VALUES (vu360UserId, vu360UserName, userGuid, email, firstName, lastName, notifyLicenseExpiration, createdDate);
    else
        UPDATE `AutoAlerts`.`User` SET `VU360UserName`=vu360UserName, `UserGuid`=userGuid, `Email`=email, `FirstName`=firstName, `LastName`=lastName, `Notify_License_Expiration`=notifyLicenseExpiration, UpdatedDate=updatedDate WHERE `VU360UserID`=vu360UserId;
    end if;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

and called this stored procedure like this

```
call usp_processUser(1231, 'abc@hotmail.com', 'aasdsad', 'abc@gmail.com', 'xxx', 'yyy', 1, '2014-06-25 08:33:40', '2014-12-05 12:00:14');
```

This procedure is executing but in workbench I am sometimes getting `165 rows effected`, sometimes `1 rows effected`.

Then I defined the same procedure like below using `on duplicate key`

```
delimiter //
create procedure usp_processUser(
    in vu360UserId bigint(20), 
    in vu360UserName varchar(255), 
    in vu360UserGuid varchar(50),
    in email varchar(50),
    in firstName varchar(255),
    in lastName varchar(255),
    in notifyLicenseExpiration bit(1),
    in createdDate timestamp,
    in updatedDate timestamp
)
begin
    insert into `AutoAlerts`.`User` (`VU360UserID`, `VU360UserName`, `UserGuid`, `Email`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Notify_License_Expiration`, CreatedDate) 
    VALUES (vu360UserId, vu360UserName, userGuid, email, firstName, lastName, notifyLicenseExpiration, createdDate)
    on duplicate key update `VU360UserName`=vu360UserName, `UserGuid`=userGuid, `Email`=email, `FirstName`=firstName, `LastName`=lastName, `Notify_License_Expiration`=notifyLicenseExpiration, UpdatedDate=updatedDate;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

and called like this

```
call usp_processUser(1231, 'def@hotmail.com', 'asdasd12312', 'abc@gmail.com', 'xxx', 'yyy', 0, NULL, '2014-12-05 12:00:14');
```

This procedure is also executing but I am continuously getting `2 rows effected`. I want to ask why `2 rows`. When I do select query like

```
SELECT * FROM User where VU360UserID = 1231;
```

Then I get only one record. I want to ask is this thing `i.e. getting message sometime 1 row, 2 rows, 165 rows effected` is workbench related or I am doing something wrong in my stored procedures?

Thanks

Comment: `VU360UserID` is define as primary key in `AutoAlerts.User table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.

Furthermore, as documented under [`CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html):

> Parameter names are not case sensitive.

Because you have named your parameters with names that differ from table columns only by lettercase and then attempt to reference those table columns without qualifiers in `WHERE` clauses (it happens that everywhere else the use of column names is unambiguous), MySQL consequently evaluates those clauses as tautologies: that is, `WHERE VU360UserID=vu360UserId` becomes `WHERE 1231=1231`—which is always true.

Therefore, in the original sproc, MySQL takes the `else` branch of the `if` statement and then updates *all* records—unless the table was originally empty, which is the only case in which it takes the `then` branch.  I presume that this correlates with the circumstances in which you saw 165 rows and 1 row affected, respectively?

In the new sproc, it happens that every column reference is unambiguous—so that is no longer your problem.  By definition, [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (with a single `VALUES` clause) only ever inserts a single row, or updates a single row: and therefore the actual number of affected rows is never more than 1.  However, to indicate to the calling application whether a row was inserted or updated, MySQL overloads the meaning of the "rows updated" response:

> With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Comment: So you mean in the StoredProcedure with `on duplicate key`. In the update case I am getting `2 rows effected` and in the insert case I am getting 1 row effected, is ok? Is it ?

Comment: Thanks :). Thanks for your explanation too. I was just calling another stored procedure whose parameter's name  differ from table columns only by lettercase and I was not getting the correct result. But after your explanation I changed the parameter's name just by prefix with i(As i stands for input). Like `in iVu360UserId bigint(20)` and now I am getting the correct result :) Thank you so much :)